# Retrofit sends multiple requests

Tags: java, android, request, retrofit, okhttp

I'm using retrofit 2 in my application. In application there's an authorization. All works right, but there is one problem still left. I have `access_token` and `refresh_token`. When I'm login in app I get my tokens. When my `access_token` expires I can get the new one with refresh token. If the refresh token expires too, I'm authorizing again for getting new tokens.
In my case when retrofit need to send call for updating my tokens, I sends data multiple times. What can be the cause of this?

```
private ApiClient(String endpoint) {
 OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

client.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
            request = request.newBuilder()
                    .header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=0")
                    .build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    supportopApi = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(endpoint)
            .client(client.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(SupportopApi.class);
}

public static synchronized void initializeInstance(String endpoint) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new ApiClient(endpoint);
    }
}

public static synchronized ApiClient getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("PentairAPIClient has not been initialized.");
    }
    return instance;
}
```

I don't want to add a big code here, so I can to add the update part too.

```
public void updateToken() {

    //Perform this call if access token is expired

    final ApiClient apiClient = ApiClient.getInstance();
    SupportObjToken supportObjToken = new SupportObjToken();

//Here I'm setting my user information for request
    supportObjToken.setGrantType("refresh_token");
    supportObjToken.setClientId(SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getUserData().getClientId());
    supportObjToken.setClientSecret(SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getUserData().getClientSecret());
    supportObjToken.setRefreshToken(SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getUserData().getRefreshToken());

//This request calls multiple times (2-3 times or more)
    Call<RefreshTokenActivation> newToken = apiClient.newToken(supportObjToken);
    newToken.enqueue(new Callback<RefreshTokenActivation>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<RefreshTokenActivation> call, Response<RefreshTokenActivation> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                String newAccessToken = response.body().getAccessToken();
                String newRefreshToken = response.body().getRefreshToken();

Here I'm saving my updated access_token
                UserData userData = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getUserData();
                SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().removeUser();
                userData.setAccessToken(newAccessToken);
                userData.setRefreshToken(newRefreshToken);
                SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().setUser(userData);

                tokenUpdaterCallback.updateToken();
            } else {
                if (response.code() == 401) {

                    //Perform this call if refresh token is expired

//This request is called multiple times too
                    Call<TokenActivation> token = apiClient.getToken("password",
                            SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getUserData().getClientId(),
                            SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getUserData().getClientSecret(),
                            SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getUserData().getEmail(),
                            SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getUserData().getPassword());

                    token.enqueue(new Callback<TokenActivation>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<TokenActivation> call, Response<TokenActivation> response) {
                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                String access_token = response.body().getAccessToken();
                                String refresh_token = response.body().getRefreshToken();

                                UserData userData = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getUserData();
                                SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().removeUser();
                                userData.setAccessToken(access_token);
                                userData.setRefreshToken(refresh_token);
                                SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().setUser(userData);


//tokenUpdaterCallback goes to main class and repeats the authorization request
                                tokenUpdaterCallback.updateToken();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<TokenActivation> call, Throwable t) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "An error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<RefreshTokenActivation> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Response is not successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Maybe your connection time is too short, Increment it and check it's fixed or not.

Comment: How to increment it?

Comment: `.connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` increase 10 to 20 or more.